# Query not returning the right rows

Tags: sql

This query returns rows that have `is_message` = 'on' and `mass_message` = 'on'

```
SELECT * 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE 
  (`sender_id` = '111' AND `recipient_id` = '222')
  OR (`sender_id` = '222' AND `recipient_id` = '111')
  AND (`is_message` != 'on' OR `is_message` IS NULL)
  AND (`mass_message` != 'on' OR `mass_message` IS NULL)
  AND `invite_for_lunch` = 'on'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How do I make sure it only returns rows that have `invite_for_lunch` = 'on'

This was originally a count, but I wanted to see what rows were being returned.

I checked the columns and no two columns out of (`is_message` , `mass_message`, `invite_for_lunch`) have `on` in the same row.

Expected result: should return 5 rows

Comment: Only `invite_for_lunch = 'on'` what about your other checks. You put a lot of ORs there.

Comment: This looks like it will do what you want `AND invite_for_lunch = 'on'` , is this not returning the results you are expecting? can you post an example of your source data, what you were expecting and what you actually got?

Comment: I fixed the indentation, which should make it a lot easier to identify logic problems.

Comment: You're probably running into operator precedence issues. You could use some extra parentheses.

Comment: You're probably being bitten by the fact that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: @Barmar Im using phpMyAdmin - ill type a sample of the data return and expected result in the original question

Comment: @Barmar You are probably right - Since my intention is to do a count, I could add the result of two separate queries with alternating sender/receiver id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fixing your parenthesis

```
SELECT * 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE 
 (  
        (`sender_id` = '111' AND `recipient_id` = '222')
     OR (`sender_id` = '222' AND `recipient_id` = '111') 
  )
  AND (`is_message` != 'on' OR `is_message` IS NULL)
  AND (`mass_message` != 'on' OR `mass_message` IS NULL)
  AND `invite_for_lunch` = 'on'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Without the extra parenthesis, the first OR is most likely be mishandled

Comment: THat returned zero rows, when it should have returned 5

Comment: the original query returns 47 rows, and again it should only return 5

Comment: why do you think it should rerturn five records?

Comment: @HLGEM I did a manual count of the rows that had `invite_for_lunch` set to 'on'

Comment: @sparky I will use two queries with count and add the result, accepting your answer since I learned something new.

Comment: yes but you have other criteria than that which have to be met

Comment: If this query is returning zero rows, then splitting it into two queries with different sender and recipient criteria will not solve it -- they'll both return zero roes.

Comment: @Barmar Im trying to copy paste the result from phpMyAdmin but it messes it up here :(

Comment: I don't use phpMyAdmin. Doesn't it have any way to export the results to a text file?

Comment: @Barmar two queries with alternating sender/receiver ID's did return the right count.

Answer (score 0):

Change your WHERE to

```
WHERE ((`sender_id` = '111'
           AND `recipient_id` = '222')
       OR (`sender_id` = '222'
           AND `recipient_id` = '111')
      )
    AND ....
```

Comment: same answer as @sparky, and same result 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is waht you want?

```
SELECT    <Insert columns names here as select * is a SQL antipattern>
FROM `messages` 
WHERE 
 (  
        (`sender_id` = '111' AND `recipient_id` = '222')
     OR (`sender_id` = '222' AND `recipient_id` = '111') 
  )
  AND 
  (
        (`is_message` != 'on' OR `is_message` IS NULL)
     OR (`mass_message` != 'on' OR `mass_message` IS NULL)
   )
  AND `invite_for_lunch` = 'on'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```